# Why does my recently released production version still got the beta tag ? [Play Store]

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My recently published app still got the beta tag and i have no idea why, because i published a production version of it.

Heres the link : [Illud-Tap the Dots (My App)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LeviathanSoftware.Illud)

So and here are some play console details :

[image]

its pretty strange, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it !

I just needed to exit the beta tester programm :)